# How do I randomise a glossy node's roughness within a specific range?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor

I have a glossy node with the roughness set to 0.05. I am using this material on many objects, and want to randomize the roughness by a small bit on each model (to be specific, between 0.02 and 0.05). I know that the way to randomize is to add an Object Info node, but what should I put between the Object Info node and the Glossy node to put the values 0.02 and 0.05 and plug into the roughness?

[image: Missing node]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An alternative to gandalf3's answer, you can use a Color Ramp:

[image]

And then set the RGB values to the appropriate number for each handle:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/wSmGsWK.png]

*Note that if you instead choose to set the Value in HSV mode (instead of RGB), you'll need to add a Gamma node just after with gamma=0.4545 (due to color space conversions; RGB mode is in sRGB color space, and HSV mode is linear)*

Answer (score 6):

All that is needed is a bit of math:

[image]

With an input of `1`: `1 * .03 = .03`, `.03 + .02 = .05`
With an input of `0`: `0 * .03 = 0`, `0 + .02 = .02`

Comment: a color ramp could do this too.